# Which is the data type to use for storing a firebase uid in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, firebase, firebase-authentication, varchar, uid

I want to store the uids generated by firebase auth in a postgres database. As it is not a valid uuid I am not sure which datatype to choose. Mainly I am not sure if I should use a char or a varchar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say use `varchar`  to allow for the `uid` changing over time. From the Postgres end there is really no difference, see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html):

> Tip

> There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text or character varying should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication UIDs are just strings.  The strings don't contain any data - they are just random.  A varchar seems appropriate.